# How to orthogonalize the "up" vector in a camera based on "eye", "look" and "up" vectors?

Tags: opengl, graphics-programming

Given a camera position defined as (eye, look, up), where "up" not quite at right angles to eye->look, how would I re-orthogonalize "up"?

I've had a hunt around, but did not find anything, yet if I recall correctly, this being a fairly classic problem for which there is an easy solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `eye` and `look` are in global space and `up` is in local space.
Then you can use this:

```
tmp = (look - eye) * up
up = normalize(tmp * (look - eye))
```

`tmp`, `look`, `eye` and `up` are 3D vectors.
`*` means cross product. `-` means usual vector subtraction.
`normalize()` is normalization function, which returns same vector but with `lenght == 1`.

If for some reason `look` is in local space, use `look` instead of `(look - eye)` in these expressions.

Comment: Note that if you normalize what you have called `tmp`, you get the camera's right/left vector (depending on the handedness of your cross product).